# Redirect to login page rather than showing a Forbidden message when not logged in

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a `authenticated_resource` decorator that prevents access to some routes if the user is not logged in.  I'd like to redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in, but right now it shows a "Forbidden" message instead.  How do I redirect?

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

```
@app.route('/metering')
@authenticated_resource
def getstats():
    token = session.get('auth_token')
    print 'token in metering =', token
    return render_template('metering.html', title='Resource Usage') 

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('auth_token', None)
    session.pop('authenticated', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('authenticated'):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)

        return abort(403) # unauthenticated

    return decorated

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != '1234':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']      
            token = auth.get_token(username, password)
            session['authenticated'] = True
            session['auth_token'] = token     
            return redirect(url_for('getstats'))

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than aborting with a 403 error, change your `authenticated_resource` to return a redirect to the login page.

```
def authenticated_resource(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'auth_token' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return decorated
```

You should *strongly* consider using [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_required) to manage the user sessions, redirection, etc. for you.